# How to know if a bluetooth device is online with it's address?

Tags: android, android-bluetooth

I am getting list of all paired devices by using method `bluetoothAdapter.getBondDevices()`. 
Is there anyway to check how many devices are actually online i.e. ready to receive data?

Comment: By saying  'ready to receive data' you mean the devices which have the bluetooth function turned on at that time?

Comment: Yes, I meant that only.

Answer (score -1):

What I'm doing in my app is to create BroadcastReceiver, and implement onReceive(), where I'm checking for BluetoothDevice.ACTION_FOUND and adding discovered devices to a list:

```
//holds names of BT devices discovered
private ArrayList<String> btDevices = new ArrayList<String>();
```

In onCreate(), create receiver:

```
private final BroadcastReceiver mReceiver = new BroadcastReceiver() {
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
        String action = intent.getAction();

        if (BluetoothDevice.ACTION_FOUND.equals(action)) {
            BluetoothDevice device = intent.getParcelableExtra(BluetoothDevice.EXTRA_DEVICE);
            if (device.getName() != null) {
                btDevices.add(device.getName());
            }
            else {
                Log.d("MyTag", "device.getName() is null");
            }
        }
    }
};
```

Then, create intent filter and register receiver:

```
IntentFilter btFilter = new IntentFilter();
btFilter.addAction(BluetoothAdapter.ACTION_STATE_CHANGED);
btFilter.addAction(BluetoothDevice.ACTION_FOUND);

registerReceiver(mReceiver, btFilter);
```

Get bluetoothAdapter and start discovery:

```
bluetoothAdapter = BluetoothAdapter.getDefaultAdapter();

//we have adapter
if (bluetoothAdapter != null) {
    //Bluetooth is OFF, so turn it on
if (!bluetoothAdapter.isEnabled()) {
        bluetoothAdapter.enable();      
    }
    else {
        bluetoothAdapter.startDiscovery();
    }
}
```

Then, I can check how many devices have been discovered with btDevices.size()